# Is there a way to inspect (using the Firebase console) the claims that have been set for a specific user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to inspect Users data from firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/)

Example:

```
UserRecord {
  uid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  email: undefined,
  emailVerified: false,
  displayName: undefined,
  photoURL: undefined,
  phoneNumber: '+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  disabled: false,
  metadata:
   UserMetadata {
     creationTime: 'Fri, 29 Mar 2019 16:58:32 GMT',
     lastSignInTime: 'Wed, 15 May 2019 09:27:35 GMT' },
  providerData:
   [ UserInfo {
       uid: '+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
       displayName: undefined,
       email: undefined,
       photoURL: undefined,
       providerId: 'phone',
       phoneNumber: '+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' } ],
  passwordHash: undefined,
  passwordSalt: undefined,
  customClaims: { test: true },
  tokensValidAfterTime: undefined 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, at the time of writing, there is no way to inspect, **from the Firebase console**, the Custom Claims that have been set for a user.

One way to inspect the Claims, is to write a Cloud Function with the following code

```
// Lookup the user associated with the specified uid.
admin.auth().getUser(uid).then((userRecord) => {
  // The claims can be accessed on the user record.
  console.log(userRecord.customClaims);
});
```

See this documentation item: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk

Comment: Here is a small script based on Renaud's code. Put this in a js file, and call it using node with your project id and the user id as arguments.

`const admin = require("firebase-admin"); 
const doIt = async () => {
    admin.initializeApp({
        projectId: process.argv[2]
    });

    const user = await admin.auth().getUser(process.argv[3]);
    console.log('user', user);
};

doIt();`